# OAuth with Azure AD v2.0: Why is expires_in now random instead of 3599?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0

I have automated tests that rely on this being 3599 and the tests passed three days ago. Now the [endpoint](https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token) is returning random values: 3741, 4069, 3683, etc. (different every time I make the request)! Is anyone else seeing this?

Comment: I still see 3599 when hitting https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/token. Is that the same endpoint you are hitting?

Comment: I am using https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token (so slightly different). Since I asked this question I've adjusted the tests to expect a value >= 3599 and the tests pass. The last few runs have reverted to seeing values of 3599 so this may have been an anomaly in the server that has since been corrected.